# JavaFX application does not start with EclipseLink Moxy

Tags: java, javafx, jaxb, javafx-8, moxy

I've added EclipseLink MOXy to my JavaFX-8 application, and since then the application does not start anymore. The error is: Could not find or load main class x.y.z. When I remove MOXy, then the application starts perfectly well. Of course then, the application doesn't use the MOXy implementation of JAXB.

The JavaFX application is packaged as a self executable jar. It includes a Weld implementation of CDI for JavaSE, and a Jersey implementation of jax-rs. I do have a jaxb.properties file in the package that contains my JAXB classes, and it does specify the JAXB context factory of MOXy.

So basically, I don't understand the reason why the application does not start anymore when MOXy is packaged within the application. Any clue?

**Edit:**
The problem may come from a jar file used as a dependency of MOXy that could be signed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's indeed a signature mismatch in the produced application JAR file.

I'm using maven to build the JavaFX application. In the build process, all the dependencies are unpacked during the package phase, and are then packed again in a single JAR file containing my application.

The unpack step is done with the maven dependency plugin. I had to add the following configuration to exclude all the signature files:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>META-INF/*.SF</excludes>
                        <excludes>META-INF/*.DSA</excludes>
                        <excludes>META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now it works.